# Why "GLProfile.GetDefault()" works while running in NetBeans but not when running Jar

Tags: java, opengl, netbeans, jar, jogl

I'm making a simple window that renders a moving triangle using the Java OpenGL libraries (jogamp) latest stable build 2.2.4, I've got everything set up like the tutorials I found on the JOGL website, the thing is while running this code on Netbeans it works fine, the method GetDefault() gets my systems OpenGL version, the window renders and also the animation. The problem is when I build the project, I make sure all the jars and .dll files are in the /dist folder and execute the Jar with "java -jar name.jar" I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.media.opengl.GLException: Profile GL_DEFAULT is not 
available on null, but: []
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:962)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:693)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:704)
    at cl.lucas.clases.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

This is my Main class code:

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

        Frame frame = new Frame("AWT Window Test");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        canvas.addGLEventListener(new EscenaSimple());

        FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it would work only on the IDE but not outside, also I'm running Windows 7, I also tried running the program on Eclipse and no problem there, the thing is the jar executable, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Your fat JAR is probably incomplete, mine works flawlessly under GNU Linux, OS X and Windows. You must follow [this layout](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Fat-Jar), you can use [this Ant script](http://forum.jogamp.org/Fat-jar-deployment-method-ant-recipe-tp4032213p4032229.html) within Eclipse to make it work. My detailed instructions are [here](http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2014/11/22/ardor3d-est-mort-vive-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation-ardor3d-is-dead-long-life-to-jogamps-ardor3d-continuation/#executablejar) and they work even though you use only JogAmp without the engine mentioned in my tutorial.

Numerous developers already asked us lots of questions about fat JARs, rather contact us on our official forum. You don't need to put the native libraries (DLLs under Windows) into a particular directory, setting the Java library path is necessary only if you don't use the JARs containing the native libraries, just keep the automated native library loading enabled (it's on by default) and GlueGen will detect your architecture, extract the proper native libraries (for JOGL, JOAL and JOCL) and load them.

If you really want to use the "-jar" option, your JAR must contain absolutely everything needed for your application to run and in the expected location. Read carefully the paragraph of my tutorial, you have to set at least the manifest attribute "Main-Class" to make it work properly, so that Java can find the main entry point of your application.